# Modifying scroll bar of a browser window using CSS

Tags: html, css, browser

I want to know how I can change the style of the scroll bar of a browser window using `CSS`. I want to change it's color and width so that I can make the webpage look more attractive and comforting for users. Can I do this with `CSS` or should I use any other languages to do that?

I would also like to know whether styling scroll bar of a browser window affects page load speed and smoothness since I have seen websites with custom scroll bars which lags while scrolling.

#### I want to change the following

```
 1. Width
 2. Color of scroll bar
 3. Color of scroll bar background
```

Here is a sample page with long enough to display a scroll bar. You may show me how to add the effect on the code below.

Sample structure code below:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Sample Page
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background:#C0C0C0;
}
.main{
    height:1200px;
    width:1000px;
}
```

Also try to include the code which works with all browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox and especially IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can design the scroll bar easily with CSS.

```
body{
background:#C0C0C0;
}
.main{
height:1200px;
width:1000px;}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background:green;
border-radius: 20px;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: red;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

for more information you can refer here. : https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cheers.

Comment: And what about Mozilla and IE? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The CSS for chrome is given above and for IE IS given below

**CSS:**

```
body{
   scrollbar-face-color: #EEC800;
   scrollbar-shadow-color: #006cb4;
   scrollbar-highlight-color:#006cb4;
   scrollbar-3dlight-color: #006cb4;
   scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #006cb4;
   scrollbar-track-color: #006cb4;
   scrollbar-arrow-color: #C1C1D1;
}
```